# Bigcommerce: How can I pass the contents of the shopping cart as JSON?

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I'm basically trying to pass the list of all products in the shopping cart as an array to a javascript analytics tracking code.

Currently I'm only able to get bigcommerce to return the last added product. How can I change this?

Comment: what kind of  contents you refer